# Value of previous row in CSV import via PHP

Tags: php, csv, import

I'm importing data from a CSV via PHP.

On some lines of the CSV, column 1 has a value, and on other lines it does not have a value. Column 2 always has a value.

If column 1 is empty and column 2 has a value, I would like column 1 to use the previous value in column 1. For example

```
|-------|-------|
| Col 1 | Col 2 |
|-------|-------|
|   A   |   2   |
|   B   |   5   |
|   C   |   3   |
|       |   1   |
|   D   |   7   |
```

Would return

```
 A2 
 B5
 C3
 C1
 D7
```

I can use prev() on an array, but as $data[0] is a string I can't use prev()

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i > 0) {  
            if ($data[0]=='' && $data[1]!=='') { 
            echo prev($data[0]).$data[1]'<br/>';
            } else { 
            echo $data[0].$data[1]'<br/>';
            }
        }
    $i++;
}
```

Banging my head against a wall for hours now, so I'd love a pointer!

Comment: Simply stash the value of column one and use it if you find it blank on a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as long as the first row is not empty...

```
$x = null;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i > 0) {
            $x = $data[0] == '' ? $x : $data[0];
            // this is like: if $data[0] is empty then use $x else say $x is $data[0].
            // Like that you can keep track of the previous value.
            // If there is one overwrite with the new one else keep the old value
            echo $x.$data[1]'<br/>';
        }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Caramba. I tried that before but had been storing the variable inside the while loop!

Comment: @charliechina no worries, that happens to all of us once. happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can store previous value in the variable and use that

```
$previousColumn1 = '';
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i > 0) {  
            if ($data[0]=='' && $data[1]!=='') { 
            echo $previousColumn1.$data[1]'<br/>';
            } else { 
            $previousColumn1 = $data[0];
            echo $data[0].$data[1]'<br/>';
            }
        }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, just storing the previous value and overwriting it any time  a new value is given will do the job.  It will assume that if the first row is blank that the `$prev` value you provide outside the loop will be used...

```
$prev = '';
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $prev = $data[0]?:$prev;
    echo $prev.$data[1].PHP_EOL;
}
```

This uses the short form of ?: to say if there is a value for `$data[0]` - then use it, otherwise use `$prev`.